# Unity mode missing in VMware 15 Workstation Player [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS]

Tags: unity, 18.04, vmware

I have recently installed VMware Workstation 15 Player on my Ubuntu 18.04 laptop and and installed Windows 7 as the guest OS in VMware. I have installed VMware Tools and everything seems fine. I wanted to try out Unity mode, but can't seem to find it under *Virtual Machine* -> *Virtual Machine Settings* -> *Options*. [The documentation](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Player-for-Windows/16.0/com.vmware.player.win.using.doc/GUID-DBC4C0EB-4161-4419-A856-EA2CE1B90DAA.html) repeatedly shows that [Unity mode can be found in the Options menu](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Player-for-Windows/16.0/com.vmware.player.win.using.doc/GUID-DA852F69-7777-4800-A306-E06345BA6C94.html). Why am I not seeing it? What am I missing?

Screenshots:

[image: Settings]
<sup>**Settings**</sup>

[image: VM Settings -> Hardware]
<sup>**VM Settings -> Hardware**</sup>

[image: VM Settings -> Options]
<sup>**VM Settings -> Options**</sup>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [VMware Workstation 12 Player Release Notes](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Player/12.0/rn/player-12-release-notes.html):

> The following features have reached end of life in Workstation 12 Player *[...and later]* and have been removed:
>
> - **Unity mode on Linux guest and host operating systems**

Unity mode on Linux guest and host operating systems has also been removed from VMware Workstation 12 and later.

Comment: That is the problem. I don't see Unity mode in the Settings -> Options Tab. I don't have access to my laptop right now. I will post a screenshot soon to clarify.

Comment: Added the screenshots in the question. You are using VMware Workstation 15 Player or Pro? Because I am also using VMware Workstation 15 Player.

Comment: @Aamir185 Unity mode was ***removed*** by VMware for Linux guests and Linux host machines in VMware Workstation 12, at least 2 or 3 years ago.  This means that you cannot use Unity mode on VMware Workstation when it is running on a Linux computer.  (This applies regardless of the guest OS in use)  There is no way to restore this functionality.  (Karel's answer is essentially the most correct one here)

Comment: great ... THE argument for me for buying vmware ws is missing noe